# Control Statement Violation inside for-loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, swiftlint

I am using SwiftLint in my app. I am getting Control Statement Violation: `if`, `for`, `guard`, `switch`, `while`, and `catch` statements shouldn't unnecessarily wrap their conditionals or arguments in parentheses. (control_statement).
What is wrong with that code? Why i am getting that waring?
Thanks in Advance

```
   for i in 0..<images.count {

        if(i == images.endIndex - 1) {
            print(i)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Its simply telling parentheses start ( and parentheses end ) symbols are now not necessary to provide in control statement' conditions so your code will go without () in control statement conditions for example your code will look like below

```
 for i in 0..<images.count {

        if i == images.endIndex - 1 {
            print(i)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have added **parentheses** in if condition.
Remove it.

```
for i in 0..<images.count {

        if i == images.endIndex - 1 {
            print(i)
        }

 }
```

You can check detail rule [here](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Rules.md#control-statement).